# Игровой движок для Android. С какого лучше начать?

Tags: android, java, разработка-игр

Здраствуйте! Я написал простую игру для андроид не использую движков. Теперь хотел бы перейти к чему-то более серьезному и так понимаю, что желательно использовать уже готовые движки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какого лучше начать и с чего начать его изучение?
Необходим 2D движок на языке Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2D: [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) или [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

Сам пишу на AndEngine. Так что о нем.

- Движок на OpenGL.
- Имеет большое количество [примеров](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/).
- Имеет никакущую документацию.
- Имеет такие расширения, как Box2D, TexturePacker, MultiTouch и др.
- [Форум](http://www.andengine.org/forums/), в принципе, изредка бывает отзывчивым.
- Работает с версией Android 1.6+. С 2.2 поддерживает OpenGL ES 2.0

Хороший [цикл](http://blog.drderico.com/category/android/andengine/) статей по движку. 
Так же на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/120716/) было 4 статьи. Правда там приводится код со старой версией движка, но почитать полезно. 
Полазайте по [wiki](http://wiki.andengine.org/AndEngine) движка.

Comment: Как думаете, с чего начать их изучение? Есть ли какие-то простые уроки, примеры?

Comment: Спасибо, информация оказалась очень полезной